# explode mesh and place all faces in one list

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to take a mesh I loaded from the THREE.JSONLoader and explode that mesh to get all the component faces into one list. However, I'm getting an error when I try to use the explode modifier.

ERROR reads: THREE.ExplodeModifier is not a constructor

I'm new to JS so I tried to figure out what exactly this error means but I'm still not sure how I'm using THREE.ExplodeModifier wrong.

I pulled the code from [this](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=mod#webgl_modifier_tessellation) example.

```js
    //site
    var siteLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    var siteMesh = null;
    siteLoader.load(
     'https://api.myjson.com/bins/zduan',
     function ( geometry, materials ) {
       var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true, transparent: true } );
       siteMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
       scene.add(siteMesh);
       renderer.render(scene,camera);
     }
    );
    //explode site

    function explodeSite(){
      if(siteMesh !== null){
        var explodeModifier = new THREE.ExplodeModifier();
        explodeModifier.modify(siteMesh);
        var numFaces = siteMesh.faces.length;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`THREE.ExplodeModifier` is not part of the main three.js library file, you need to explictly include the `ExplodeModifier.js` file. From the sample you linked to:

```
<script src="js/modifiers/ExplodeModifier.js"></script>
```